# drive not working in clean ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

I have installed ubuntu clean ubuntu 14.04.1.
ubuntu made a default drive having mountpoint '/' in ex4 partion and a swap.
i have deleted that both drive and again created a extra dive as in windows(d:, e:) by mounting the one drive using a /media/private and other drive  using /media/project in ex4.

The main problem is after completing the installation when i open that drive i can't do anything.i cannot paste any files there, cannot make any folder, infact it is not behaving as a logical drive..
so guys please help me out solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
chmod -Rf 777 /media/private
chmod -Rf 777 /media/project
```